# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"

Tags: postgresql

I have a parent table `layer_1_` and a number of child tables `layer_1_points`, `layer_1_linestrings` etc. which contain some geometry data. Each child table has its own geometry constraint. So, for example, `layer_1_points` has this constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom_geom CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'POINT'::text)
```

Whereas `layer_1_linestrings` table has this constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom_geom CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'LINESTRING'::text)
```

Many other layer tables have similar names: `layer_2_`, `layer_3_`, ..., `layer_N_`. And all of them have their own child tables. What I want to achive is that when a user inserts to a parent table (`layer_N_`), then this `insert` statement should be forwarded to a particular child table (`layer_N_points` etc.). So, for example, when I do:

```
INSERT INTO layer_1_ (geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 3857))
```

I should actually insert to `layer_1_points`, because `geom` type is `POINT`. To achive all this I created this trigger function and the trigger itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_layer_insert() 
  RETURNS trigger AS 
$$ 
DECLARE 
    var_geomtype text;
    table_name text;
    layer_id text := (TG_ARGV[0])::text;
BEGIN
    var_geomtype := geometrytype(NEW.geom);    
    IF var_geomtype = 'POINT' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_points'));
    ELSIF var_geomtype = 'MULTIPOINT' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_multipoints'));       
    ELSIF var_geomtype = 'LINESTRING' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_linestrings'));
    ELSIF var_geomtype = 'MULTILINESTRING' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_multilinestrings'));
    ELSIF var_geomtype = 'POLYGON' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_polygons'));
    ELSIF var_geomtype = 'MULTIPOLYGON' THEN
        table_name := (SELECT concat ('layer_', layer_id, '_multipolygons'));
    END IF;

    EXECUTE '
        INSERT INTO ' || table_name || ' 
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT NEW.*) AS t
    ';

    RETURN NULL;   
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_layer_1_ BEFORE INSERT
ON layer_1_ FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_layer_insert(1);
```

However, when I do actual insert like:

```
INSERT INTO layer_1_ (geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 3857))
```

I get an error message:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"
LINE 3:         SELECT * FROM (SELECT NEW.*) AS t
                                  ^
QUERY:  
    INSERT INTO layer_1_points 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT NEW.*) AS t
```

So, what is wrong with `SELECT NEW.*` and how can I fix it? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I also tried this:

```
EXECUTE '
    INSERT INTO ' || table_name || ' 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT NEW.*) AS t
' USING NEW;
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: Replace `NEW` by `$1` in the string: `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || ' SELECT * FROM SELECT $1.*) AS t' USING NEW;` to assuming it as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, it works! You may make a complete answer from your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you execute something using PLPGSQL statement `EXECUTE` it runs in the different context so local variables is not visible there. To pass variable(s) the `EXECUTE '<SQL script>' USING <variables list>;` form is used:

```
EXECUTE 'insert into table(field1, field2) values ($1, $2)' USING var1, var2;
```

So the statement should be:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || ' SELECT * FROM SELECT $1.*) AS t'
      USING NEW;
```

But much more secure is using `format` function:

```
execute format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT * FROM SELECT $1.*) AS t', table_name)
```

Comment: Who would have thunk it?

Comment: The syntax can be simplified : `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || table_name || ' values ($1.*)' USING NEW;`

Comment: are there some missing '(' above ?